# Render Parent Class View in Child Class

Tags: php, oop, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

MY LoginController class is extended from UserController. I want to ovverride one method of UserController. Everything works fine but $this->render('index') call the view of child class. I want to call the view of parent class. I have tried using parent::render('index') but taht dodn't work too. Here is my code

```
<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use mdm\admin\models\form\Login;
use mdm\admin\models\form\PasswordResetRequest;
use mdm\admin\models\form\ResetPassword;
use mdm\admin\models\form\Signup;
use mdm\admin\models\form\ChangePassword;
use mdm\admin\models\User;
use mdm\admin\models\searchs\User as UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\base\UserException;
use yii\mail\BaseMailer;
use mdm\admin\controllers\UserController;

class LoginController extends UserController
{
    
   public function actionLogin()
    {
        //parent::actionLogin();
        if (!Yii::$app->getUser()->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new Login();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->getRequest()->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return parent::render('login', [
                    'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

The error i am getting is
[image]

But my opinion is that it should call the parent class view instead of looking it in child class. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html#named-views):

> If the view name starts with a single slash `/`, the view file path is formed by prefixing the view name with the view path of the currently active module. If there is no active module, `@app/views/ViewName` will be used. For example, `/user/create` will be resolved into `@app/modules/user/views/user/create.php`, if the currently active module is `user`. If there is no active module, the view file path would be `@app/views/user/create.php`.

So use:

```
return $this->render('@mdm/admin/views/user/login', ['model' => $model]);
```

Comment: it is still looking for file in frontend/views rather then view file of parent class which is in vendor folder

Comment: Its not in the frontend but in vendors folder. And by giving full path or replicate the view file in frontend would definitely work. But what i want is like $this call the render in current class context and i want to call the render in parent class context. Is it possible?

Comment: If it's composer-installed extension it should get automatic alias like `@name` so try `@mdm` (answer updated)

Answer (score 2):

the view normally are not organized  by class .. so you should call the view you need ..

eg for login view

```
     return $this::render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

or for another view name  named: my_new_view_login in (`views/your_controller/my_new_view_login.php`)

```
        return $this::render('my_new_view_login', [
                'model' => $model,
        ]);
```

Comment: The view file is in vendor folder but by trying your solution it still look for it in frontend/views

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a full path to view file. If it's an extension, use path from alias

```
return $this->render('@mdm/admin/views/user/login', ['model' => $model]);
```

Comment: The view file is in vendor folder but by trying your solution it still look for it in frontend/views

Comment: You still need to use full path, but an absolute one from base module namespace. I've edited answer.